# C program using struct and scanf produces error: expected expression before ‘ROBOT’

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I have a C program where I am trying to set `struct` values with scanf.  I get an error:

```
s.c: In function ‘main’:
s.c:15:17: error: expected expression before ‘ROBOT’
```

From this code:

```
enum DIRECTION {N,E,S,W};     

typedef struct {
   int xpos;
   int ypos;
   enum DIRECTION dir;
} ROBOT;

int main() {
   int x, y, i;
   char string[20];
   printf("Enter x coordinate: \n");
   scanf("%i", &ROBOT.xpos);
}
```

What does this error mean and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `&ROBOT.xpos`, what is `ROBOT`? You need to have `ROBOT robot;` somewhere there.

Comment: Next time please post the error so users can easily identify the problem.

Comment: Writing `scanf("%i", &ROBOT.xpos);` is like writing `scanf("%i", &int);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ROBOT` is the name of the type, like `int`, you need to declare a variable of this type.

```
ROBOT r;
printf("Enter x coordinate: \n");
scanf("%i", &r.xpos);
printf("Enter y coordinate: \n");
scanf("%i", &r.ypos);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an actual struct (`ROBOT`) object.

```
ROBOT r;
scanf("%i", &r.xpos);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do the following

```
typedef struct {
   int xpos;
   int ypos;
   enum DIRECTION dir;
} ROBOT;
```

you first define an anonymous `struct` type and then you give a name `ROBOT` to this type using the `typedef` keyword. `typedef` defines a new name for a type. So here `ROBOT` is a type name just like `int`, `float` etc., not a variable. You declare a variable of this type just like you declare variable of any type, i.e.,   `typename var_name;`.

```
ROBOT bot;  // bot is a variable of type ROBOT
// do stuff with bot

printf("Enter x coordinate: \n");
scanf("%i", &ROBOT.xpos);
printf("Enter y coordinate: \n");
scanf("%i", &ROBOT.ypos);
```

Also note that the conversion specifier `%i` reads an integer in base 16 if it begins with 0x or 0X, in base 8 if it begins with 0, and in base 10 otherwise. The `%d` specifier always reads in base 10, i.e., a decimal integer. Unless you really need `%i`, always use `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

The `typedef` in your definition of `ROBOT` means that `ROBOT` is the struct type itself, not *a* robot. Declare a `ROBOT myRobot` in your `main()` function, and pass that in instead.